# PHP: How to convert binary string into normal string in order to avoid MySql "Illegal mix of collations" error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encoding, binary-string

I am having lot of problems processing CSVs with `ñ,é`, and all of those non ASCII chars, and saving those words in MySQL.

In order to solve this I created a CSV that contains in one cell this data:

```
iphonée@3,;= ÑÑñe x
```

I know that if I can save this word I will solve the problem.

The thing is that when I process the CSV I get this cell as

```
b"iphonée@3,;= ÑÑñe x"
```

Binary String!!. So when I do a select in my database using this data, I get this error:

```
QueryException {#1695
  #sql: "select * from `seller_product_languages` where `seller_product_id` = ? and `lang` = ? and `name` = ? and `description` = ? and `description_html` = ? and `bullet_html` is null and `bullet` = ? and `meta_keywords` is null limit 1"
  #bindings: array:6 [
    0 => 102
    1 => "es"
    2 => b"iphonée@3,;= ÑÑñe x"
    3 => "negro"
    4 => "negro"
    5 => ""
  ]
  #message: b"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' (SQL: select * from `seller_product_languages` where `seller_product_id` = 102 and `lang` = es and `name` = iphonée@3,;= ÑÑñe x and `description` = negro and `description_html` = negro and `bullet_html` is null and `bullet` =  and `meta_keywords` is null limit 1)"
  #code: "HY000"
  #file: "/home/vagrant/Code/...../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
  #line: 664
  -previous: PDOException {#1694
    #message: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='"
    #code: "HY000"
    #file: "/home/vagrant/Code/..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
    #line: 330
    +errorInfo: array:3 [
      0 => "HY000"
      1 => 1267
      2 => "Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='"
```

My column type is `VARCHAR(255)`, but Im also using `TEXT` type.

So, if I don't use non ASCII chars on my string, I get a normal string (not a binary string) and I can save it perfectly. The problem is when I add `Ñéá` or any weird character, I get a binary string and that binary string makes my database crush.

I looked and all `seller_product_languages` columns are UTF-8 with default collation.

So here is the thing:

**How can I convert a binary string into a normal string? And how can I detect that the string is a binary string in order to make this conversion?**

Thats the only solution I thought of, if you think you have another one, I would be grateful.

P.S.: The closest I get to the solution was doing:

```
            $arr = unpack("a*",$binary_string);
```

But I get only the ASCII chars:

```
$arr[1] =iphon�e@3,;= ���e x
```

Environment :

- PHP 7.2
- Laravel 5.5
- Apache
- Ubuntu 18.04

> ```
> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'c%'
>
> character_set_client  utf8
> character_set_connection  utf8
> character_set_database    utf8
> character_set_filesystem  binary
> character_set_results utf8
> character_set_server  latin1
> character_set_system  utf8
> character_sets_dir    /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
> check_proxy_users OFF
> collation_connection  utf8_general_ci
> collation_database    utf8_general_ci
> collation_server  latin1_swedish_ci
> completion_type   NO_CHAIN
> concurrent_insert AUTO
> connect_timeout   10
> core_file OFF
> ```

```
show create table seller_products;

CREATE TABLE `seller_products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `subcategory_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subcategory_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `sku` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `width` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stock` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999',
  `country_iso` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_usd` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `tax_usd` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `shipping_usd` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `total_amount_usd` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `discount_applied` decimal(5,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `hs_code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pickup_address` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `seller_sku` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chargeable_weight` decimal(6,3) NOT NULL,
  `gross_weight` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_weight` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_length` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_width` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_height` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `warehouse` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pickup_shipping_usd` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `seller_fee_usd` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `fullfilment_usd` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `seller_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sku_UNIQUE` (`sku`),
  KEY `reseller_product_subcategory_idx` (`subcategory_id`),
  KEY `seller_products_unique` (`sku`),
  KEY `seller_product_address_idx` (`pickup_address`),
  CONSTRAINT `reseller_product_subcategory` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategory_id`) REFERENCES `subcategories` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `seller_product_address` FOREIGN KEY (`pickup_address`) REFERENCES `merchant_addresses` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


show create table seller_product_languages



 CREATE TABLE `seller_product_languages` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON 
   UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `seller_product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `bullet` text,
      `description` text,
      `meta_keywords` text,
      `lang` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `description_html` text,
      `bullet_html` text,
      `default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `index3` (`seller_product_id`,`lang`),
      KEY `fk_seller_product_languaje_seller_products1_idx` 
    (`seller_product_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_seller_product_languaje_seller_products1` FOREIGN 
   KEY (`seller_product_id`) REFERENCES `seller_products` (`id`) ON 
   DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: `Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='` -- that looks like the relevant issue. So _which_ things are specifying the "illegal mix"? I don't see a table or query, so..

Comment: The thing is "Why if instead of a binary string I have a normal string, this error does not happen?"

Comment: So which things are specifying the "illegal mix"? <-- that probably leads to an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your point of view, I didn't realice that before. I hope this can lead us to the answer :)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'c%'` -- we can probably point to the inconsistency that is leading to the error.

Comment: Hello! I just add those two things!. Thank you, hope it can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it changing in the `config/database.php` file, the `'mysql'` array:

It was in:

```
'mysql' => [
           ... 
           'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
           'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
           ... 
        ],
```

And I change it to:

```
'mysql' => [
           ... 
           'charset' => 'utf8',
           'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
           ... 
        ],
```